# Ionic module error

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, lodash

I ran app on my device for the first time. It wasn't working as it was in the browser (no background picture, login API not working)...anyway, after that my device froze, I forcefully shut it down, and after that as if something on computer got mixed up or something. When I try to run app now, i get:

```
module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'lodash-node'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Marko\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\xmlbuilder\lib\index.js:5:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Marko\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\xmlbuilder\lib\index.js:14:4)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
```

I tried reinstalling node, I tried with lodash install and cache clean...does anyone know how to fix this =/

Upon running (still same error after):

```
$ npm i --save lodash-node
npm WARN onload-script failed to require onload script npm-autoinit/autoinit
npm WARN onload-script Error: Cannot find module 'npm-autoinit/autoinit'
npm WARN onload-script     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
npm WARN onload-script     at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
npm WARN onload-script     at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
npm WARN onload-script     at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
npm WARN onload-script     at cb (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:289:9)
npm WARN onload-script     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:382:14
npm WARN onload-script     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:82:7
npm WARN onload-script     at Array.forEach (native)
npm WARN onload-script     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:81:13
npm WARN onload-script     at f (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\once\once.js:17:25)
npm WARN onload-script  { [Error: Cannot find module 'npm-autoinit/autoinit'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
npm WARN onload-script failed to require onload script npm-autoinit/autoinit
npm WARN onload-script Error: Cannot find module 'npm-autoinit/autoinit'
npm WARN onload-script     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
npm WARN onload-script     at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
npm WARN onload-script     at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
npm WARN onload-script     at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
npm WARN onload-script     at cb (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:289:9)
npm WARN onload-script     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:382:14
npm WARN onload-script     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:82:7
npm WARN onload-script     at Array.forEach (native)
npm WARN onload-script     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:81:13
npm WARN onload-script     at f (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\once\once.js:17:25)
npm WARN onload-script  { [Error: Cannot find module 'npm-autoinit/autoinit'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
npm WARN package.json roko@1.1.1 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json roko@1.1.1 No README data
npm WARN package.json roko@1.1.1 No license field.
npm WARN deprecated lodash-node@3.10.2: This package has been discontinued in favor of lodash@^4.0.0.
lodash-node@3.10.2 node_modules\lodash-node
```

Comment: Afaik, the module name is 'lodash', not 'lodash-node'

Comment: What version of node are you using?

Comment: I have reinstalled with the latest installer

Comment: delete  your projects  node modules.and reinstall with `npm i`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error on Windows when trying to install *any* Node.js module.

Solved the issue by running `npm config delete onload-script npm-autoinit/autoinit`.

I still got a bunch of warnings

```
$ npm config delete onload-script npm-autoinit/autoinit
npm WARN onload-script failed to require onload script npm-autoinit/autoinit
npm WARN onload-script Error: Cannot find module 'npm-autoinit/autoinit'
[ . . . ]
npm WARN onload-script  { [Error: Cannot find module 'npm-autoinit/autoinit'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
```

but after that I was able to install modules without problems.

Source: [Github comment](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/12600#issuecomment-217795940)